# RO Account in Oracle PL SQL, changing the value of some cells just in the query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of a Equipment, where there's stored:
Timestamp of action
the action (e.g. start, finish, abort, ..)
current location
source
destination
ID of Box.

Now I figured out a Query, where I visualize for every box, where it started, when it started, where it really went and when it went there.

That's useful for us, since sometimes the box will not go to the desired destination and so we can visualize later, where it went wrong, when the current location != destination and job state = finish.

Only problem is, sometimes the Database stores the wrong values for the startlocation.

So I want to figure out, how to use my already existing query and replace the source with current location always when the current action = 'start'

---

```
SELECT JOB_NAME, startLocation, endLocation, REAL_DESTINATION, startEvent, endEvent, Starttime, 
endTime from
(
    SELECT JOB_NAME, NEW_STATUS as startEvent , CURRENT_LOCATION, SOURCE as startLocation, TIMESTAMP 
    as Starttime, 
    LEAD(CURRENT_LOCATION, 1) OVER (PARTITION by JOB_NAME order by TIMESTAMP) as DESTINATION, 
    LEAD(TIMESTAMP, 1) OVER (PARTITION by JOB_NAME order by TIMESTAMP) as endTIME,
    LEAD(NEW_STATUS, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_NAME order by TIMESTAMP) as endEvent,
    LEAD(DESTINATION, 1) OVER (Partition by JOB_NAME order by TIMESTAMP) as endLocation 
    from my_table
    WHERE TIMESTAMP >= to_date(sysdate-3)
    AND NEW_STATUS in ('Started', 'Finished', 'Canceled') AND OLD_STATUS not in ('Started', 
    'Finished', 'Canceled')
    AND TIMESTAMP >= to_date(sysdate-7)
    ORDER BY JOB_NAME, Starttime asc
)
WHERE STARTEVENT = 'Started'
AND ENDEVENT != 'Started'
```

I want something like: If startEvent = 'started' then SourceLocation = CurrentLocation

Comment: Ok, if `startEvent = 'started' then SourceLocation = CurrentLocation` and what about else ?

Comment: Also, you are currently not selecting SourceLocation  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `case when` be the right solution for you?

```
SELECT JOB_NAME
       , startLocation
       , endLocation
       , startEvent
       , endEvent
       , Starttime
       , endTime 
       , case when startEvent = 'started'then CURRENT_LOCATION
              else null
         end SourceLocation 
from (SELECT JOB_NAME
             , NEW_STATUS as startEvent 
             , CURRENT_LOCATION
             , SOURCE as startLocation
             , "TIMESTAMP" as Starttime
             ,  LEAD(CURRENT_LOCATION, 1) OVER (PARTITION by JOB_NAME order by "TIMESTAMP") as DESTINATION
             ,  LEAD("TIMESTAMP", 1) OVER (PARTITION by JOB_NAME order by "TIMESTAMP") as endTIME
             ,  LEAD(NEW_STATUS, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_NAME order by "TIMESTAMP") as endEvent
             ,  LEAD(DESTINATION, 1) OVER (Partition by JOB_NAME order by "TIMESTAMP") as endLocation 
      from my_table
      WHERE "TIMESTAMP" >= to_date(sysdate-3)
      AND NEW_STATUS in ('Started', 'Finished', 'Canceled') 
      AND OLD_STATUS not in ('Started', 'Finished', 'Canceled')
      AND "TIMESTAMP" >= to_date(sysdate-7)
      ORDER BY JOB_NAME, Starttime asc
);
```

**Note**:

1. You are selecting REAL_DESTINATION and there is no such column in your sub-query

Comment: Hi @Nanex123 a feedback from you would be nice. Is this answer ok ? Do you need something else ? If it is ok you can accept it. Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: That did the trick. Query above was just a bit messy, because I still was working on it. Sorry for that! But sure, that got me in the right direction!

Comment: Hi @Nanex123 thank you for your feedback. Happy to help. Cheers!